# How to use add_action from outside a class

Tags: wordpress

I am learning about wordpress code and have read a lot of posts about add_action, but haven't found one yet that fits my situation. I want to make use of a hook that exists in another WP plugin. In rough outline, it looks like this:

```
// This part is not my code
class CDH {

    function do_stuff() {
        // important stuff
        do_action( 'hook_i_want_to_use', $parameter );
        // more stuff
    }

    global $cdh;
    $cdh = new CDH();
}

// My first attempt code:
add_action( 'hook_i_want_to_use', 'my_function', 10, 1 );

function my_function( $parameter ) {
    echo $parameter;
}

// My second attempt code:
class my_CDH extends CDH {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'hook_i_want_to_use', array( $this, 'my_function' ), 10, 1 );
    }

    function my_function( $parameter ) {
        echo $parameter;
    }
}
```

In both attempts, my_function() is never called. How do I hook on to the do_action in the instance $cdh?

Comment: Your first attempt is correct since `do_action` is just a placeholder to execute scripts. It really depends on what that `do_stuff()` method is really doing and what `$parameter` is. Is it an array? sting? object?

Comment: Ok that helps. What I posted here is really just a rough outline. In reality what I'm calling do_stuff() is hundreds of lines and has 6 parameters. The important thing though is that I know that do_stuff() is running, so I don't know why my add_action() isn't being picked up. Anyway I will go back to the first attempt version and look at it again, to see if the do_action is being skipped over somehow in the plugin code. Thanks!